# Subversion client for Diff/Compare (Mac)

Tags: xcode, svn, compare, diff, svnx

I'm looking for a (free) subversion client that gives a complete DIFF/Compare between two revisions. Xcode's Source Control comparison tool only compares one file at a time, and doesn't give you a list of files updated between two revisions.

I tried to use svnX, but i'm unable to configure it with my local repository using:

> svn+ssh://username@server-machine.local/Users/Path/subversion/ProjectName/

Any suggestions regarding an appropriate subversion client, and/or how to make svnX to work?

Answer (score 0):

The best tool that I have found is [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).  It is an add on for eclipse but you can use it to manage your repository as well.

Collabnet also offers a product called [Collabnet Destktop](http://desktop-eclipse.open.collab.net/) that includes the subclipse client.

One major caveat is that you have to install the JavaHL library.  Make sure to **read the [OS specific](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5bf26515097c3231c1b04dfdb22c036bc511926b) directions**!

You might have to play with it a bit but the repository browser is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I use svnX in Mac OS 10.7.5, You can download [svnX for Max OS X here](http://code.google.com/p/svnx/downloads/list).

There are some server they provide free/private Space for subversion. I used this [free/private space from Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/free-private-subversion-repository-only/prepare_copy?type=private)

Here is screenShot that shows how to setup svnX in Mac OS X.
[image]

[image]

In working copy you can see difference in revision. svnX uses fileMerge to show difference. Its one of the best subversion client for mac os x.

Comment: The problem I'm having is with local SVN repository (that's placed on a network system). Have you ever tried to setup svnX with local SVN repository?